# How to find potential intersections between two user paths?

Tags: ios, geolocation, geospatial, computational-geometry

I'm currently working on an app that constantly tracks the user's location in order to determine potential intersection points between the path of the user and those infected with contagious diseases. The paths of infected individuals (or patients) are manually created and inserted into the application as geojson files.

The issue I'm facing is how to figure out potential intersections. A "user location point" is uniquely defined by a latitude, a longitude, an accuracy (in meters), and a timestamp. A "patient location point" is defined in the same way. However, because of the question of accuracy, it is best to think of these not as points, but rather as circles. Location points, in combination, make up a path.

Given two such paths, what would be a good algorithm for determining where/when (an) intersection(s) occurred and the possibility of intersection as a percent?

P.S. How would this algorithm change if we want to determine the intersection within some time range, like five minutes?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the problem geometrically, you can cast it in 3D space with coordinates (X, Y, T). The trajectory of a person is a curve which is monotonous in the direction of time. If you take into account the spatial indeterminacy, you have a "tube" instead of a curve.

Assuming that the trajectories are defined as line segments traversed at constant speed, what you can do is to consider all trajectory vertices in increasing time (actually you will perform a merge of the timeline for both persons). Then, between two consecutive events, determine the minimum distance between the two portions of line segments facing in time (in fact the horizontal distance). If the distance falls below a tolerance, then you had a meeting.

More precisely, assume that the persons are at A0 and B0 at time t0 and A1, B1 at time t1, the horizontal distance is given by (A0 - A1 + t (B1 - A1 - B0 + A0))². Developing, you have a quadratic expression in t which is easy to minimize. Don't forget that t is constrained to [t0, t1].

Assuming that the trajectories have N and M vertices over the considered time period, the computational workload will be linear, O(N + M).

If you also allow a time tolerance, I guess that it suffices to modify the way to compute the minimum distance, by adding a delta-time term.

In any case, the problem amounts to finding the shortest distance between lines segments, in 3D.